# Помогите найти ошибку PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Помогите найти ошибку.
Не вычисляется второй **`x`**, пишет **`0.0`** в таблице.

Это программа:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
from Kui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bp)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.bp_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.bp_3)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.bp_4)

    def bp(self):
        try:
            self.text = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.text)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(self.text)
            self.ui.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(1)
            self.ui.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(self.text)
            self.ui.tableWidget_3.setColumnCount(1)
            self.ui.tableWidget_3.setRowCount(self.text)
        except:
            result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Ошибка", "Введите целое число")
            return

    def bp_2(self):
        D = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())#D - кол-во колонн и строк в матрице 
        H = [[0] * D for i in range(D)]
        for i in range(D):
            for j in range(D):
                item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(i, j).text()             
                item = item if item else '0'
                item = item.replace(',','.')
                try:
                    item == float(item) 
                    H[i][j] = float(item) 
                except:
                    result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Ошибка", "Введите вместо букв цифры")
                    return
            j = 0
        i = 0
        M =[]
        while i != D:
            item = self.ui.tableWidget_2.item(i, 0).text()
            item = item.replace(',','.')
            try:
                item == float(item)
                M.insert(i, float(item))
            except:
                result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Ошибка", "Введите вместо букв цифры")
                return
            i = i + 1
        H_det = np.linalg.det(H)
        for j in range(D):
            HL = H
            for i in range(D):
                HL[i][j] = M[i]
            x = np.linalg.det(HL) / H_det
            self.ui.tableWidget_3.setItem(j, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(x)))

    def bp_3(self):
        self.ui.tableWidget.clearContents()
        self.ui.tableWidget_2.clearContents()
        self.ui.tableWidget_3.clearContents()

    def bp_4(self):
        result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Справка", "Если вы не знаете, как работает программа. Следуйте данным простым шагам:  \n\n Шаг №1: Ввод кол-ва переменных. Нажмите 'Ввод' ; \n Шаг №2: Запишите в таблицы переменные, которые лежат в уравнении рядом с X. Так же запишите и цифры, лежащие после занка '='. Числа после '=' обозначаются буквой 'b'. \n Шаг №3: Нажмите кноку 'Решение' и в таблице ниже появится ответ. \n\n Так же есть кнопка 'Очистка', для удаления информации из ячеек таблицы, если вдруг вы захотите написать новые переменные.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Это интерфейс:

```html
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(933, 486)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 611, 311))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.groupBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 431, 281))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 161, 281))
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 120, 181, 311))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.groupBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
        self.tableWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_3)
        self.tableWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 161, 281))
        self.tableWidget_3.setObjectName("tableWidget_3")
        self.tableWidget_3.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget_3.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_3.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_3.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 80, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 241, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 140, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 19, 60, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 531, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setItalic(False)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 90, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 40, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 933, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Шаг 2: Ввод переменных "))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b"))
        self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", " Решение данной системы:"))
        item = self.tableWidget_3.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_3.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "x"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Шаг 1:  Выбор кол-ва переменных "))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение СЛАУ методом Крамера"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистка"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Справка"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: добавьте модуль `Kui.py` - вы опубликовали два модуля `main.py`

Comment: Добавил интерфейс

Answer (score 0):

**`Модуль copy`** - поверхностное и глубокое копирование объектов.

Операция присваивания не копирует объект, он лишь создаёт ссылку на объект.
Для изменяемых коллекций, или для коллекций, содержащих изменяемые элементы,
часто необходима такая копия, чтобы её можно было изменить,
не изменяя оригинал.
Данный модуль предоставляет общие (поверхностная и глубокая) операции копирования.

Разница между поверхностным и глубоким копированием существенна только для
составных объектов, содержащих изменяемые объекты
(например, список списков, или словарь, в качестве значений
которого - списки или словари).

**`Глубокая копия`** создает новый составной объект,
и затем рекурсивно вставляет в него копии объектов, находящихся в оригинале.

Вам надо заменить строку:

```
HL = H
```

на строку:

```
HL = copy.deepcopy(H)
```

---

Я также поправил другие погрешности, которые мне попались на глаза.

---

```
import sys
import copy                                                          # +++
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

#from Kui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(933, 486)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 611, 311))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.groupBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 431, 281))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 161, 281))
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 120, 181, 311))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.groupBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
        self.tableWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_3)
        self.tableWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 161, 281))
        self.tableWidget_3.setObjectName("tableWidget_3")
        self.tableWidget_3.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget_3.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_3.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_3.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 80, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 241, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 140, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 19, 60, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 0, 531, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setItalic(False)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 90, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 40, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: white\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 933, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Шаг 2: Ввод переменных "))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b"))
        self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", " Решение данной системы:"))
        item = self.tableWidget_3.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget_3.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "x"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Шаг 1:  Выбор кол-ва переменных "))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Решение СЛАУ методом Крамера"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистка"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Справка"))
        

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bp)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.bp_2)   
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.bp_3)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.bp_4)

    def bp(self):
        try:
            self.text = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
            
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.text)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(self.text)
            
            self.ui.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(1)
            self.ui.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(self.text)
            
            self.ui.tableWidget_3.setColumnCount(1)
            self.ui.tableWidget_3.setRowCount(self.text)
        except:
            result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, "Ошибка", "Введите целое число")
            return

# Решение
    def bp_2(self):
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()                               # +++
        if not text:                                                 # +++
            result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, "Ошибка", "Введите количество переменных.")        
            return
        
        D = int(text)  # D - кол-во колонн и строк в матрице         # + text
        H = [[0] * D for i in range(D)]
        
        for i in range(D):
            for j in range(D):
#                item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(i, j).text()
                item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(i, j)                # +++
                item = item.text() if item else '0'                  # +++
#                item = item if item else '0'
                item = item.replace(',','.')
                
                try:
# ?                    item == float(item) 
                    H[i][j] = float(item) 
                except:
                    result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                        self, "Ошибка", "Введите вместо букв цифры")
                    return

# ?            j = 0
            
        i = 0
        M =[]
        while i != D:
#            item = self.ui.tableWidget_2.item(i, 0).text()
            item = self.ui.tableWidget_2.item(i, 0)                     # +++            
            item = item.text() if item else '0'                         # +++
            item = item.replace(',','.')
            try:
# ?                item == float(item)
                M.insert(i, float(item))
            except:
                result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                    self, "Ошибка", "Введите вместо букв цифры")
                return
                
            i = i + 1
        
        H_det = np.linalg.det(H)

        for j in range(D):

# -            HL = H                                          # --- # <----          
            HL = copy.deepcopy(H)                              # +++ # <---- 

            for i in range(D):
                HL[i][j] = M[i]
                
            x = np.linalg.det(HL) / H_det

            self.ui.tableWidget_3.setItem(j, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(x)))

    def bp_3(self):
        self.ui.tableWidget.clearContents()
        self.ui.tableWidget_2.clearContents()
        self.ui.tableWidget_3.clearContents()

    def bp_4(self):
        result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            "Справка", 
            "Если вы не знаете, как работает программа. "
            "Следуйте данным простым шагам:  \n\n Шаг №1: Ввод кол-ва переменных. "
            "Нажмите 'Ввод' ; \n Шаг №2: Запишите в таблицы переменные, "
            "которые лежат в уравнении рядом с X. "
            "Так же запишите и цифры, лежащие после занка '='. "
            "Числа после '=' обозначаются буквой 'b'. \n Шаг №3: "
            "Нажмите кноку 'Решение' и в таблице ниже появится ответ. \n\n "
            "Так же есть кнопка 'Очистка', для удаления информации из ячеек таблицы, "
            "если вдруг вы захотите написать новые переменные.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @OlegZ что не так?